# How do I loop through a set of 10 images more than once?

Tags: loops, cocos2d-iphone

I have a code block in cocos2d that creates a background by cycling through a set of 10 images like so:

```
- (void)addBackground{
    CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

    //Add images to batchNode
    float maxReach = 0;
    for (int imageNumber=1; imageNumber < 13; imageNumber++) {
        CCLOG(@"Adding image intro%d.png to the introAnimation.",imageNumber);
        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"national_scenery_part%d-iPad.png",imageNumber]];
            background.position = ccp((winSize.width/2)+maxReach, winSize.height/2);
            [self addChild:background z:0];
            maxReach = maxReach + background.contentSize.width;
        } else {
            CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"national_scenery_part%d.png",imageNumber]];
            background.position = ccp((winSize.width/2)+maxReach, winSize.height/2);
            [self addChild:background z:0];
            maxReach = maxReach + background.contentSize.width;
        }
    }
}
```

But of course it only loops once. I'd like it to loop 3 times. I was thinking of setting an integer to 0 and add 1 at the end of each loop and then run it again until it reaches 3. Does that sound like the best way to do this?

Comment: for something that simple any way that works is the best ;)

Comment: But does it sound like that would work?

Comment: why not try it? Sounds more than reasonable to me.

Comment: I did, it seems to work.  But I seem to have an image that gets presented and truncated by its next sibling.  Its the only one and thus at the end of the first cycle, there is a respective "hole" of the same size by which the image gets truncated at the end.  Not sure why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nested FOR/WHILE loop for repeating it 3 times.

It should work well. I don't see any issue using this.